# Importing in functions instead of at the beginning or the script?

Tags: python

Quick background: writing a module. One of my objects has methods that may or may not be successfully completed - depending on the framework used underneath my module. So a few methods first need to check what framework they actually have under their feet. Current way of tackling this is:

```
def framework_dependent_function():
    try:
        import module.that.may.not.be.available
    except ImportError:
        # the required functionality is not available
        # this function can not be run
        raise WrongFramework 
        # or should I just leave the previous exception reach higher levels?

[ ... and so on ... ]
```

Yet something in my mind keeps telling me that doing imports in the middle of a file is a bad thing. Can't remember why, can't even come up with a reason - apart from slightly messier code, I guess.

So, is there anything downright wrong about doing what I'm doing here? Perhaps other ways of scouting what environment the module is running in, somewhere near `__init__`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This version may be faster, because not every call to the function needs to try to `import` the necessary functionality:

```
try:
    import module.that.may.not.be.available
    def framework_dependent_function():
        # whatever
except ImportError:
    def framework_dependent_function():
        # the required functionality is not available
        # this function can not be run
        raise NotImplementedError
```

This also allows you to do a single attempt to `import` the module, then define all of the functions that might not be available in a single block, perhaps even as

```
def notimplemented(*args, **kwargs):
    raise NotImplementedError
fn1 = fn2 = fn3 = notimplemented
```

Put this at the top of your file, near the other imports, or in a separate module (my current project has one called `utils.fixes`). If you don't like function definition in a `try`/`except` block, then do

```
try:
    from module.that.may.not.be.available import what_we_need
except ImportError:
    what_we_need = notimplemented
```

If these functions need to be methods, you can then add them to your `class` later:

```
class Foo(object):
    # assuming you've added a self argument to the previous function
    framework_dependent_method = framework_dependent_function
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to larsmans suggestion but with a slight change

```
def NotImplemented():
    raise NotImplementedError

try:
    import something.external
except ImportError:
    framework_dependent_function = NotImplemented

def framework_dependent_function():
    #whatever
    return
```

I don't like the idea of function definitions in the `try: except:` of the import

Comment: This shadows the first definition of the `framework_dependent_function`.

Comment: @Jakob:  You have to put *both* `def` blocks ahead of the `try`, otherwise your `NotImplemented` version will always get rebound to the `def` below.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `imp.find_module` (see [here](http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html)) in order to check for the presence of a specific module.